# Passing in path to another file to an exe run from inside a Java program

Tags: java, io, cygwin

I'm writing a Java program, that needs to run an exe file compiled by cygwin. After running it, it needs to enter two lines of queries (each ending by \n). and on the third line it will receive an answer. I need to read that answer to process in the rest of the program.
The second line that I'm inputting is the path to another file! If I run the same command from CMD or from cygwin and input that path it works, but when I'm entering the path (hardcoding it in my Java program), the invoked exe file returns that there is no such file. Is there any special path instruction in this case?
(I have the following code which runs the program and gets the program output, but before getting my desired result, the exe gives an error that there is no such file and exits!

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Users/Armen/Downloads/oll-0.03/oll_line.exe","P");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process cmd = pb.start();
PrintWriter pWriter = new PrintWriter(cmd.getOutputStream());
pWriter.println("L C:/Users/Armen/workspace/recurdom/model0fsupernew");
pWriter.flush();
//HERE IT GIVES ME THE ERROR
//pWriter.close();
InputStream is = cmd.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
line = br.readLine();
System.out.println("here received: "+line);
//pWriter.println("T +1 5:1 51:1 70:1 92:1 121:1 142:1 181:1 202:1 215:1 250:1 272:1 291:1 330:1 347:1 371:1 409:1 423:1 449:1 481:1 513:1 521:1 522:-1 523:-1 524:-1 525:-1 526:-1 527:-1 528:-1 529:-1 530:-1 539:1");
//pWriter.flush();
```

Comment: I'm not sure, for the path shouldn't you use `\\ ` instead of `/` ?

Comment: Thank you @Thronghar! I was thinking so, but turned out / or \\ both work in starting the external program but when giving it as input parameter, none of them works. I even tried passing in a file in my current Dir so it doesn't need a path but still it doesn't find the file. Maybe when calling a program from inside another program there is a limitation or a path change?

Comment: Did you add the path to the `bin` directory (`C:\cygwin\bin`) in your windows PATH, si it can find `cygwin1.dll` maybe ?

Comment: Yes! the program that is compiled with cygwin runs from my Java, but then it asks me to give the path to another file that it needs to do computation on. This second text file's path is not recognized!

Comment: (the program i'm calling is oll machine learning program. it runs from inside my java call, but then to test my results i can either use the exe file oll_line.exe where I will need to give the path to my model file and then enter test instances one by one, receiving the predictions. )

Comment: (or I should use the oll_test.exe file giving as argument my test instances file. oll_test works fine, since passing the path as argument works, but this needs my every test instance which is being generated, be written on file then and then predict.)

Comment: (This involves 10K+ disk I/O, but if i could pass the path as an input (not a call argument) to oll_line.exe, I wouldn't need any disk I/O!) sorry for this being so long!

Comment: Maybe putting the path in a string variable, then giving it in argument to `pWriter.println()` it'll work. I don't know.